# PrintDocument / PrintPreviewDialog Nothing Draws or Prints

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I am playing around with the PrintDocument and PrintPreviewDialog classes to learn them, but I cannot seem to get the document to print anything when sent to the printer, and also nothing draws at all in the PrintPreviewDialog, not even a white blank page, it is all grey.  Ive tried changing margins, draw locations, drawing giant rectangle, etc., nothing shows up.  I am not very familiar with GDI+ so I am sure I am missing something, but I cannot find what.

Here is the relevant code I am using:

```
//Print
private void menuPrint_click(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    printDocumentPage = 0;

    printDocument1.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
    printDocument1.BeginPrint += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventHandler(printDocument1_BeginPrint);

    printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
    printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
}

private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    // Save our print action so we know if we are printing 
    // a preview or a real document.
    printAction = e.PrintAction;

    // Set some preferences, our method should print a box with any 
    // combination of these properties being true/false.
    printDocument1.OriginAtMargins = false;

    if (printAction != PrintAction.PrintToPreview)
    {
        PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
        printDocument1.DocumentName = "Print Document Simple Text";
        printDlg.Document = printDocument1;

        // Show printer dialog
        if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.PrinterSettings = printDlg.PrinterSettings;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}

void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    RectangleF marginBounds = e.MarginBounds;

    RectangleF printableArea = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea;

    //if (printAction == PrintAction.PrintToPreview)
        //g.TranslateTransform(printableArea.X, printableArea.Y);

    int availableWidth = (int)Math.Floor(printDocument1.OriginAtMargins ? marginBounds.Width : (e.PageSettings.Landscape ? printableArea.Height : printableArea.Width));
    int availableHeight = (int)Math.Floor(printDocument1.OriginAtMargins ? marginBounds.Height : (e.PageSettings.Landscape ? printableArea.Width : printableArea.Height));

    //g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 0, 0, availableWidth - 1, availableHeight - 1);

    // Doesnt work either
    //g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 0, 0, 100, 100);

    System.Drawing.Font myFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Underline, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    float lineHeight = myFont.GetHeight(g);
    float yLineTop = e.MarginBounds.Top;

    if (printDocumentPage >= m_report.PageCount)
    {
        e.HasMorePages = false;
        return;
    }

    otPage page = m_report.pageAt((int)printDocumentPage);

    for (int i = 0; i < page.LineCount ; i++)
    {
        otLine line = page.lineAt(i);

        g.DrawString(line.getPrintLine(true), myFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

        yLineTop += lineHeight;
    }

    printDocumentPage++;

    if (printDocumentPage < m_report.PageCount)
    {
        e.HasMorePages = true;
        return;
    }

    e.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

The PrintPreviewDialog appears, and both event handlers are run, it loops through the lines correctly and draws each of them, but nothing is drawn on the dialog and when sent to the printer, it prints empty pages.  The PrintPreviewDialog is all grey, no white pages or anything, and zooming at all levels does nothing.

**EDIT:**  Getting rid of my current page/line handling and just trying to draw a single string, any string, or rectangle, *something* nothing works.

Here is a screenshot of the print preview screen.  Changing the zoom/pages does nothing either: [image]

**EDIT2:**

I downloaded this very simple example project from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/printpreviewcontrol-in-c-sharp/ which I assume works as intended.  Straight out of the box this does the same thing.  Only a grey screen shows (and the button on the form).  Nothing prints in the printpreviewcontrol at all.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT3:**

I tested this on another development machine and it works fine.  Why wouldnt it work on my computer?  The other computer is 64 bit whereas this is 32, but was built with same settings.  Could it be my .NET framework is messed up?

**EDIT4:**

Sorry for all the edits.  Ive found that if I switch my default printer, it works perfectly.  Something to do with the e.MarginBounds.